# Can you restrict a Swift generic constraint to a set of known types?

Tags: swift, macos, generics

Given a basic Swift `struct` with a generic constraint like so:

```
struct MetadataValue<T> {
  var value:T

  init(_ value:T) {
    self.value = value
  }
}
```

Is there any way to constrain `T` such it can only be **one** of a certain type of allowed types? ex:

```
struct MetadataValue<T> where T:Double or T:Bool or T:String {
  ... 
}
```

I know that I can use composition to "and" the constraints, but can I "or" the constraints somehow?

**Goal:**

The use-case scenario is for me to be able to store metadata properties and their corresponding values from things like images and videos. I track hundreds of different properties, but each property's value is a known type: like a String, Integer or Double but obviously can't be any arbitrary type that a generic `T` might accidentally accept.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Can I "or" the constraints somehow?

No, you cannot. However, this will accomplish the same objective.

Define a new protocol:

```swift
protocol MetadataRawValue { }
```

Add your conforming types:

```swift
extension Double: MetadataRawValue { }

extension Bool: MetadataRawValue { }

extension String: MetadataRawValue { }
```

And finally:

```swift
struct MetadataValue<T> where T: MetadataRawValue {
  ... 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
protocol MetadataValueType {}

extension Double: MetadataValueType {}
extension Bool: MetadataValueType {}
extension String: MetadataValueType {}

struct MetadataValue<T: MetadataValueType> {
   ...
}

let md = MetadataValue<Double>(10.0) // OK
let mb = MetadataValue<Bool>(true) // OK
let ms = MetadataValue<String>("string") // OK
let mf = MetadataValue<Int>(10) // error: type 'Int' does not conform to protocol 'MetadataValueType'
```